# Filling pseudo 3D canvas shapes

Tags: canvas, 3d, polygon, fill, shapes

Currently I'm playing around with pseudo 3D shapes in canvas 2d context. However, I stuck yet at filling the shape sides.

Here's the drawing function I wrote:

```
Shape.prototype.draw = function (ctx) {
    var offsetX = ctx.canvas.width / 2;
    var offsetY = ctx.canvas.height / 2;

    var i = this.edges.length;
    while (i--) {
        var vertex1 = this.rotatedVertexs[ this.edges[i][0] ];
        var vertex2 = this.rotatedVertexs[ this.edges[i][1] ];

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(vertex1[0] + offsetX, vertex1[1] + offsetY);
        ctx.lineTo(vertex2[0] + offsetX, vertex2[1] + offsetY);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
    }
};
```

...and a simple example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/xYZyU/

Any ideas what I'm doin' wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your drawing function works in "Lines", not "Faces" of the square.

You cannot fill a line. You need at least two lines in the same path to create a fill-able area. (note that every time you're calling `beginPath`, you're making a new path. Your longest path is only ever one line segment)

If we look at drawing only three of the lines you have, we get something like this:

[image]

There's no "face" to fill there, and you need to reorganize your code until you're drawing the difference faces of the square all at once, so that you have something to actually fill.